# Need help understanding CMake basic expression conditionals

Tags: cmake, conditional-statements

I'm trying to understand CMake conditionals, specifically basic expressions.

I've read the CMake documentation:

> if(<constant>)
> True if the constant is 1, ON, YES, TRUE, Y, or a non-zero number (including floating point numbers). False if the constant is 0, OFF, NO, FALSE, N, IGNORE, NOTFOUND, the empty string, or ends in the suffix -NOTFOUND. Named boolean constants are case-insensitive. If the argument is not one of these specific constants, it is treated as a variable or string (see Variable Expansion further below) and one of the following two forms applies.

> if(<variable>)
> True if given a variable that is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise, including if the variable is undefined. Note that macro arguments are not variables. Environment Variables also cannot be tested this way, e.g. if(ENV{some_var}) will always evaluate to false.

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`, where I'm trying to look for patterns in the configuration step output to correlate to the documentation:

```
set(VAR1 "TRUE")
message("VAR1: ${VAR1}")

if (VAR1)
  message("if (VAR1) True")
else()
  message("if (VAR1) False")
endif()

if (${VAR1})
  message("if (\${VAR1}) True")
else()
  message("if (\${VAR1}) False")
endif()

if ("${VAR1}")
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") True")
else()
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") False")
endif()

if (TRUE)
  message("if (TRUE) True")
else()
  message("if (TRUE) False")
endif()
message("")

set(VAR1 "FALSE")
message("VAR1: ${VAR1}")

if (VAR1)
  message("if (VAR1) True")
else()
  message("if (VAR1) False")
endif()

if (${VAR1})
  message("if (\${VAR1}) True")
else()
  message("if (\${VAR1}) False")
endif()

if ("${VAR1}")
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") True")
else()
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") False")
endif()

if (FALSE)
  message("if (FALSE) True")
else()
  message("if (FALSE) False")
endif()
message("")

set(VAR1 "foo")
message("VAR1: ${VAR1}")

if (VAR1)
  message("if (VAR1) True")
else()
  message("if (VAR1) False")
endif()

if (${VAR1})
  message("if (\${VAR1}) True")
else()
  message("if (\${VAR1}) False")
endif()

if ("${VAR1}")
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") True")
else()
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") False")
endif()

if (foo)
  message("if (foo) True")
else()
  message("if (foo) False")
endif()
message("")

set(VAR1 0)
message("VAR1: ${VAR1}")

if (VAR1)
  message("if (VAR1) True")
else()
  message("if (VAR1) False")
endif()

if (${VAR1})
  message("if (\${VAR1}) True")
else()
  message("if (\${VAR1}) False")
endif()

if ("${VAR1}")
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") True")
else()
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") False")
endif()
message("")

set(VAR1 3)
message("VAR1: ${VAR1}")

if (VAR1)
  message("if (VAR1) True")
else()
  message("if (VAR1) False")
endif()

if (${VAR1})
  message("if (\${VAR1}) True")
else()
  message("if (\${VAR1}) False")
endif()

if ("${VAR1}")
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") True")
else()
  message("if (\"\${VAR1}\") False")
endif()
message("")
```

This is the corresponding output:

```
VAR1: TRUE
if (VAR1) True
if (${VAR1}) True
if ("${VAR1}") True
if (TRUE) True

VAR1: FALSE
if (VAR1) False
if (${VAR1}) False
if ("${VAR1}") False
if (FALSE) False

VAR1: foo
if (VAR1) True
if (${VAR1}) False
if ("${VAR1}") False
if (foo) False

VAR1: 0
if (VAR1) False
if (${VAR1}) False
if ("${VAR1}") False

VAR1: 3
if (VAR1) True
if (${VAR1}) True
if ("${VAR1}") True
```

My question is about the `if (${VAR1})` variant: **why, when `VAR1` has value `TRUE`, do I get the output `if (${VAR1}) True`, whereas when `VAR1` has value `foo`, do I get the output `if (${VAR1}) False`?**

I have a half-baked understanding here, but the verbiage in the documentation is also confusing to me, so I wanted to ask if my reasoning/reading of the documentation is correct:
My understanding is that given `if (${VAR1})`, the `${VAR1}` is expanded before the `if()` itself is evaluated. Do the two conditions, therefore, become `if (TRUE)` versus `if (foo)`? Are they therefore evaluated under the "if(<constant>)" rule? If yes, then because `TRUE` is in the enumerated set of recognized constants, it is evaluated accordingly, but since `foo` is not in the enumerated set, it is evaluated as "if(<variable>)" (and since variable `foo` is not defined, the condition is false)?

Comment: "Do the two conditions, therefore, become `if (TRUE)` versus `if (foo)`?" - Yes, and the following considerations are correct too. And this is what is written in the documentation you have cited: Firstly, CMake attempts to follow `if(<constant>)` rule. If the parameter is not a known constant, then CMake follows `if(<variable>)` rule.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - thank you; your comment answers my question. Does CMake expand `${}` recursively until no more expansion is possible? E.g. first `if (${${VAR2}})` would be expanded twice, next the sequence that you described would occur: attempt to follow `if(<constant>)` rule; if the parameter is not a known constant, then follows `if(<variable>)` rule -- is that what would occur?

Comment: "Does CMake expand ${} recursively until no more expansion is possible?" - No, and this is too written in the documentation you cited: The condition in `if(<variable>)` is evaluated to "True if given a variable that is defined to a value that is not a false constant. False otherwise, including if the variable is undefined.".